# Can we use Angular Material 2 with Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I wanted to know if we can use angular material 2 http://material.angular.io with Ionic 2? Or is it unnecessary? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unnecessary...Ionic 2 includes material design on its own. Plus all the controls are custom made for mobile (which I assume you are targeting since Ionic is targeted to mobile apps).

Comment: Ionic 2 now serves desktop/web apps too. I think there should be support for that too